# Type holder in std C++

Tags: c++, types

Is there in std C++ library anything like this?:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeHolder { using type = T; };
```

i.e. special structure that is only used to pass a type around and store it. The idea is that I want to pass it inside functions by value, like:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/aPoWWbT54)

```
void f(auto th) { typename decltype(th)::type val{}; }
void h() {
    auto g = [](auto th){ typename decltype(th)::type val{}; };
    f(TypeHolder<int>());
    g(TypeHolder<int>());
}
```

Of cause I can pass a type as `template <typename T>` but right now I want to pass it by value as one of auto-function's and/or non-templated lambda's params.

There exists [std::integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) that can be somewhat usable for type holding, but it is not suitable for me because I don't want to provide value and/or instantiate value of my type. More than that I have non-structural types hence I can't provide its value inside std::integral_constant.

Sure I can use templated structure `TypeHolder` mentioned above in code, but I'm looking for std-library based solution if it exists, not to reinvent wheel.

Comment: Look at `std::tuple` for this.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Tuple needs to hold value of type and I don't want to instantiate value of my type, I just want to pass type around without value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C++20, you can use [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) which is exactly the type you want.

```
f(std::type_identity<int>());
g(std::type_identity<int>());
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hfhTdchP8)

Comment: Can you please see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918037/) which is similar but for holding compile time value?